# How can I unit test this C# extension method?

Tags: c#, unit-testing

I'm just not sure how to mock up a situation to test this.  Should I actually create a file on the file system?

```
public static void DeleteIfExists(this FileInfo fileInfo)
{
   if (fileInfo.Exists)
   {
      fileInfo.Delete();
   }
}
```

Comment: It could fail if somebody changes the implementation and breaks it.  :-)

Comment: I would create a file. Just like when I test db, I first insert a new record so I have a dummy to test the delete method...

Comment: @BrunoLM - Why would you do this instead of using RhinoMocks?

Comment: is this an example of trying to write a unit test, when it is really an Integration test?

Comment: @Mike I just think it is a simple task, I would just keep it simple. I wouldn't use RhinoMocks just for this, unless your server has some limitations that prevents you from writing and deleting the file right away. But if you are going to use RhinoMocks on your entire project then go for it :P

Comment: Get rid of the extension method and just call FileInfo.Delete. If the file does not exist, FileInfo.Delete does nothing. See http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.fileinfo.delete.aspx

Answer (score 8, accepted):

I'd use a mocking framework, like [RhinoMocks](http://nuget.org/List/Packages/RhinoMocks).

```
[Test]
public void ShouldDeleteAFileWhenItExists()
{
    var mockInfo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<FileInfo>();
    mockInfo.Expect( i => i.Exists ).Return( true ).Repeat.Once();
    mockInfo.Expect( i => i.Delete() ).Repeat.Once();

    var extensions = new FileInfoExtensions();

    extensions.DeleteIfExists( mockInfo );

    mockInfo.VerifyAllExpectations();
}

[Test]
public void ShouldNotDeleteAFileWhenItDoesNotExist()
{
    var mockInfo = MockRepository.GenerateMock<FileInfo>();
    mockInfo.Expect( i => i.Exists ).Return( false ).Repeat.Once();
    mockInfo.Expect( i => i.Delete() ).Repeat.Never();

    var extensions = new FileInfoExtensions();

    extensions.DeleteIfExists( mockInfo );

    mockInfo.VerifyAllExpectations();
}
```

Other tests for when Delete throws an exception, etc.

Comment: Working with this now. Can you expand on your last sentence?  I'm a super noob.

Comment: @Mike - you need to consider all the different possibilities for what could happen and what you want the code to do in that eventuality.  What should happen if Delete throws an exception?  Maybe you want it to swallow certain types of exceptions (FileNotFoundException, for example), others you want to bubble up.  Write your test to ensure that the code does what you want, then modify the code so that it passes the test.  You need to decide what it should do, then write the test that will force you to write the code to make it happen.  I just didn't want to imply that those two tests were all.

Comment: while that works, it exposes the internal logic of the method under test: the contract with the outside world is "Delete a file if it exists", but we are not constrained by how we achieve that.... what if an implemenation calls Exists() twice? Those tests enforce that the method has been implmented a certain way, which seems wrong to me...

Comment: @Mitch - you can relax the constraints if you want to allow freedom.  It's just some sample code and there are plenty of other ways to do it.  In my world, I thought "I just want it to see if the file exists and then delete it" so it really should only call exists once.  If I later decided that I wanted it to ensure that the file didn't exists afterwards, I could relax the constraints or add an additional expectation that made sure that it was verified.

Comment: My point is, those tests enforce a particular implementation.

Comment: @Mitch - this is a test to use a FileInfo object to check if a file exists and, if so, delete it.  Seems reasonable to me to require that it use the Exists property and the Delete method. After all I'm writing the test to help me write the code so it's not unreasonable to expect that it will drive the design.  Now you might want some other tests -- acceptance tests, for example, if this were part of an API, that did some black box testing that would actually create a file then make sure it gets deleted, but that seems overkill for an unit test of an extension method on a mockable class.

Comment: Testing whether the `Delete` member was called feels wrong. What if the method was changed to get the full path of the file and then just called `File.Delete(path)`? Surely, this is a correct implementation...

Comment: @tvanfosson: I think this is an abuse of testing. A test should not rely on a specific internal implementation.

Comment: @Tomas - Why? Remember this is an extension method.  What we are trying to do is make sure that interacts with the class the way we want, not that it figures out a way to delete a file that might not use the class we're extending.  We just want to provide a short-cut for some code that uses this class, not some other class, and the test drives that behavior.

Comment: @Mitch - it's an extension method! we're not trying to invent a new way of deleting a file, we're trying to reduce a bit of code replication for a pattern that checks to see if a file exists before we delete it using an object of the class we're extending.  In this case it **is** the specific invocation of the methods we care about, not whether a file actually gets deleted.  We trust that the class we're extending works.

Comment: @tvanfosson: Granted it's an extension method. We will have to agree to differ.

Comment: Thanks for the dialogue.  Trying to soak up as much knowledge as possible.